# Combine options in inputdialog

Tags: input, vim, dialog

I often use the inputdialog to execute a command using:

```
  let n = confirm({msg} [, {choices} [, {default} [, {type}]]])
```

p.e. search numbers
if n == 1 --> p.e. do search of all numbers with '.,'
if n == 2 --> p.e. do search of all exponential numbers
if n == 3 --> p.e. do search of all numbers with 3 digits
etc

but with this method I can only choose one argument.

Is there a way in Vim where you can chose multiple arguments together in an inputdialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround, use `input()` function, let the user to choose multiple options and split them into a list to process them. An example:

Add next function to `vimrc` or similar file:

```
func My_search()
    let my_grouped_opts = input ( "1.- Search one\n2.- Search two\n3.- Search three\n" )
    let my_list_opts = split( my_grouped_opts, '.\zs' )
    for opt in my_list_opts
        echo "Option number " opt " selected"
    endfor
endfunction
```

Call it:

```
:call My_search()
```

There will appear your options:

```
1.- Search one
2.- Search two
3.- Search three
```

Select them like:

```
23
```

And the function will split them into a list.

Comment: Thanks Birei, something strange happens when I insert the 1st character in the commandline... the cursor moves 20 spaces to the right. I can't find what it is. Do you have an idea? (Btw I use the function in menu.vim)

Comment: found it in the help file. I had to put `:call inputsave()` and `:call inputrestore()` around the input line. :)

Comment: I do a check to see if the input is only digits. If not I return an error output. Do you know how to visualize it? The error output can not be seen with a long list of `my_grouped_opts` items.

Comment: @Remonn: I don't understand you.  How about adding `echo "\nERROR processing options"` and `return` after the `input` statement?

Comment: I added this after the input statement: `if matchstr(my_grouped_opts, '[^0-9]') != '' | echo "Wrong Input" | return | endif` but I can't see the error output because the commandline with my_grouped_opts (+ echo output) returned to default after the matchstr has found a wrong input. Hope I made myself clear :)

Comment: @Remonn: How many entries do you have in `input` function? It seems to work for me like this: `let my_grouped_opts = input ( "..." ) | if matchstr(my_grouped_opts, '[^0-9]') != '' | echo "Wrong Input" | return | endif` regardless of number of lines. It let me read the message until I press `INTRO`.

Comment: found it. I have added `:set hls<CR>` after I call the function, in order to highlight the matches. That didn't let me see the echo message. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `input()` to prompt the user to input a string, and then inspect the returned list:

```
let string = input( {msg}, {choices}, ... )
```

For example, the user could enter `1,2,3`, and you can do a text comparison of this string:

```
if ( string =~ 1 )
    " do something
endif

if ( string =~ 2 )
    " do something
endif

if ( string =~ 3 )
    " do something
endif
```

A more sophisticated approach (e.g. if there are more than 9 options) might be to split the string into a list:

```
let choice_list = split( string, ',' )

for choice in choice_list
    if choice == 1
        " do something
    endif
    if choice == 2
        " do something
    endif
    if choice == 3
        " do something
    endif
endfor
```

Since the returned string could be anything the user decides to enter, you might want to add some sanity checks that the string is indeed a list of integers.